# Why can't I decompile System.IdentityModel.Services.dll?

Tags: wif, asp.net-identity, decompiling, ildasm, ilspy

I am trying to decompile `System.IdentityModel.Services.dll` but none of the decompiling tools show the method details

I cannot even get the IL for these methods in ILDASM.  Same story for ILSpy.

for example:  `System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule`

ILDASM:

```
.method family hidebysig newslot virtual 
        instance void  OnAuthenticateRequest(object sender,
                                             class [mscorlib]System.EventArgs eventArgs) cil managed
{
  // Code size       0 (0x0)
} // end of method SessionAuthenticationModule::OnAuthenticateRequest


.method family hidebysig instance class [mscorlib]System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1<class [mscorlib]System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity> 
        ValidateSessionToken(class [System.IdentityModel]System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityToken sessionSecurityToken) cil managed
{
  // Code size       0 (0x0)
} // end of method SessionAuthenticationModule::ValidateSessionToken
```

I had thought at least the IL was always available.  Is this not the case?

Comment: I would guess that you are not decompiling the actual code assembly, but rather a reference assembly (which contains only metadata).  If a disassembler shows a code size of zero, then there's no method bodies to show.  The "real" assembly may be stored elsewhere (%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET, the GAC, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

r# is capable of finding the microsoft reference sources and Reflector is capable of generating :

```
    protected ReadOnlyCollection<ClaimsIdentity> ValidateSessionToken(SessionSecurityToken sessionSecurityToken)
{
    ReadOnlyCollection<ClaimsIdentity> onlys;
    SessionSecurityTokenHandler handler = base.FederationConfiguration.IdentityConfiguration.SecurityTokenHandlers[typeof(SessionSecurityToken)] as SessionSecurityTokenHandler;
    if (handler == null)
    {
        throw DiagnosticUtility.ExceptionUtility.ThrowHelperError(new InvalidOperationException(SR.GetString("ID4011", new object[] { typeof(SessionSecurityToken) })));
    }
    try
    {
        onlys = new ReadOnlyCollection<ClaimsIdentity>(handler.ValidateToken(sessionSecurityToken, this.CookieHandler.Path));
    }
    catch (SecurityTokenExpiredException exception)
    {
        throw DiagnosticUtility.ExceptionUtility.ThrowHelperError(new FederatedSessionExpiredException(DateTime.UtcNow, sessionSecurityToken.ValidTo, exception));
    }
    catch (SecurityTokenNotYetValidException exception2)
    {
        throw DiagnosticUtility.ExceptionUtility.ThrowHelperError(new FederationException(SR.GetString("ID1071", new object[] { DateTime.UtcNow, sessionSecurityToken.ValidFrom }), exception2));
    }
    return onlys;
}
```

> ILSpy is
>   generating very similar code.  So I guess you are looking at the wrong
>   assembly or missing something else.